# Does ontological claim not have its separate existence?

Tags: epistemology, ontology

Considering these definitions: 
**Ontology** is the philosophical study of the **nature of being, becoming, existence, or reality**, as well as the basic categories of being and their relations. 
**Epistemology** is the study of knowledge and justified belief.

My question: 
The act of knowing (inherent epistemological claim) itself reveals the existence of the object in consideration - (inherent ontological claim). And it is obvious as there must be an object of knowledge before knowing the object.

- Does it follow, every epistemological claim is by product of ontological claim? Or In other words, Is there any epistemological claim of an object without dealing **inherently** with its ontology?

Comment: `before knowing the object` Strictly speaking, that "before"-existence is not necessary, in general. It is necessary in some schools of thought and not in other. Those latter would say it's suffice the object is correlative (always accompanies) the awareness or knowledge of it.

Comment: Note also that there are forms of acts of mind which pose their objects as specially _nonexistent_ ones - I mean not absent here or impossible things - but being here by mode of wanting. This when we experience a subject of art, for example.

Comment: But mind can't think about an object it has never experienced. E.g can you imagine a new color? @ttnphns

Comment: I can return to your objection: you can't either imagine exactly same colour twice. In the end, you'll end with a _sentence_, ok, (let it be) green!

Comment: I can't imagine a new color, but I can imagine a program that would solve the problem I am having right now.  And when I write it, the last line, that makes it actually run correctly and therefore be what I specified can only exist once I have known it.